# Is a question of opium and appendectomy on-site here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have this question, which is related to a friend of mine. Is it on-site for me to ask it here? I can't find any related site in Stack Exchange suite of sites:

Appendectomy means to cut appendix, because of some reasons. However, some of patients feel a severe pain after the surgery.

If a patient is an addict to opium, then is it OK to let him consume the opium as a anti-pain medicine?

Answer (score 5):

This question asks for medical advice, which is off-topic for Biology and all SE sites. Additionally, it involves the use of illegal drugs, which we can't comment on for obvious reasons. If you or a friend is having pain after surgery, see the surgeon or your primary care doctor.